# I've used printf but when I complie nothing appears

Tags: c

When I comnpile And run the program nothing appears,i'm using codeblocks 17.12 please help me.
ANSWER: To make the result of printf appear you should end the cycle with ctrl+z or ctrl+d depending if you are using windows or linux.

```
main()
{
int nc;
for (nc=0; getchar() !=EOF; ++nc);
printf("%d\n", nc);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193735/discussion-on-question-by-francesco-venuti-ive-used-printf-but-when-i-complie-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for (nc=0; getchar() !=EOF; ++nc);

the ';' at the end of the line is perhaps not what you want, because of it the body of the *for* is empty

so `printf("%d\n", nc);` is executed only one time, not several, and for that you need first to go out of the *for*, so to reach EOF

What is your OS, what are you doing to have EOF ?

If you never reach EOF it is normal to have nothing print

If you are under Linux/Unix you can do `echo blahblah | ./yourprog` and yes in that case you will print 9 (because of the newline, 8 if `echo -n blahblah`)

Under Windows do not execute your code through codeblocks, execute it directly in a terminal, codeblocks and other IDE have unexpected behavior on the input/output